# Reading lines from big string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am slicing out a big chunk of text from a file. Now the chunk is stored in a variable. Like,

```
str="from child hood days i liked sweet and savoir. in the early days my mother cooked great deal of sweet meats in home and all my relatives had a nice taste for good sweets. even in remote assam town we thronged miles to procure good sweets. and my sweet eating habit was pretty known. in my childhood i could had as good as 30 to 40 rosgollas at one seating after a full course of lunch. though i was not among the best in my family."
```

But I now want to read each line in the same way as we write as

```
for line in file:
     print line
```

My question is can we do this, or should I write back to the file and then do the operation? If any one can kindly help.

Regards,
Subhabrata Banerjee
Gurgaon India

Comment: If you want to read each line, just read line by line from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the string into a `StringIO.StringIO` and then you can use file operations on it. Do note that your sample text only has one line in it though.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in str.split('\n'):
    doit(line)
```

Though that is not <strike>reading</strike> parsing lazily. For **really** big chunks <strike>read</strike> parse lazily:

```
for match in re.finditer(r'(.*)\n', str):
    print match.group(1)
```

Comment: Why not? Are they eaten up by Cookie Monster?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a string tokenizer to handle the 'big string' by splitting it up into the 'smaller strings'. This will make the process a lot easier. By the way, what are you coding in?